# Apache Spark Scala - Hive insert into throwing a "too large frame error"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to insert data into Hive using below code, it is always getting failed with

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame:'.`

I tried tweaking the memory but didn't help.

Here are the details.

Error stack trace:

```
[Stage 4:=====================================================>(999 + 1) / 1000]18/11/27 09:59:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 364.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 1367, spark-node, executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.SparkHiveDynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeToFile(hiveWriterContainers.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable$$anonfun$saveAsHiveFile$3.apply(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable$$anonfun$saveAsHiveFile$3.apply(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Too large frame: 5587345928
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:357)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:332)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:54)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.SparkHiveDynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeToFile(hiveWriterContainers.scala:286)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5587345928
at org.spark_project.guava.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.decodeNext(TransportFrameDecoder.java:133)
at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:81)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
... 1 more
```

Below is my sample  code:

```
 //create spark session first
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("MSSQLIngestion")
      .master("yarn")
      .config("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "false")
      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1000")
      .config("spark.shuffle.spill", "true")
      .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseG1GC")
      .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
      .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate();

    spark.sql("set hive.exec.parallel=true")

    // Create a Properties() object to hold the parameters.
    val connectionProperties = new Properties()
    connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)
    connectionProperties.setProperty("fetchSize", "100000")

    // read data from JDBC server and construct a dataframe
    val jdbcDF1 = spark.read.jdbc(url = jdbcUrl, table = (select * from jdbcTable) e, properties = connectionProperties)

    val jdbcDF = jdbcDF1.repartition(1000)

    val count = jdbcDF.count()

    println("red "+count+" records from sql server and started loading into hive")

    // if count > 0 then insert the records into Hive
    if (count > 0) {
      // create spark temporary table
      jdbcDF.createOrReplaceTempView("sparkTempTable")
      // insert into Hive external table
      spark.sql("insert into externalTable partition (hivePartitionCol) select * from sparkTempTable  distribute by  hivePartitionCol ")
    }
    println("completed the job for loading the data into hive")

    spark.stop()
```

Here is my spark-submit:

`spark-submit --class com.generic.MSSQLHiveIngestion --master yarn --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 16G --driver-memory 8G --driver-cores 4 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1G  data-ingestion.jar`

Answer (score 3):

This problem happens due to having too big objects to shuffle.

Can you try to increase suffle partitions ?

`.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1000")`

Or Can you try to add this config:

`.config("spark.shuffle.spill.compress", true)`

`.config("spark.shuffle.compress", true)`

Or can you lower the block size to lower shuffle memory usage

Comment: Thanks but how can I lower the block size to lower shuffle memory usage?

Comment: You are using default compression format (lz4), so you can set a block size to less than the default value (32k) by setting `.config(“spark.io.compression.lz4.blockSize”, 16k)`

Answer (score 3):

When the size of the shuffle data blocks exceeds the limit of 2 GB, which spark can not handle, the following error occurs.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5211883372140375593
            at org.sparkproject.guava.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
            at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.decodeNext(TransportFrameDecoder.java:148)
```

---

#### Option 1 (>= Spark2.2):

1. `>= Spark2.2` handles this issue in a better way when compared to other lower versions of Spark. For information, see [SPARK-19659](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19659).
2. Use the following Spark configuration:
   Modify the value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` from the default `200` to a value greater than `2001`.
   Set the value of `spark.default.parallelism` to the same value as `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`.

#### Option 2:

1. Identify the DataFrame that is causing the issue.
   a. Add a Spark action(for instance, `df.count()`) after creating a new DataFrame.
   b. Print anything to check the DataFrame.
   c. If the print statement is not executed for a DataFrame, then the issue is with  that DataFrame.
2. After the DataFrame is identified, repartition the DataFrame by using `df.repartition()` and then cache it by using `df.cache()`.
3. If there is skewness in the data and you are using Spark version earlier than 2.2, then modify the code.